# How to add a layer on a RasterStack in a specific position?

Tags: raster, r

I have the RasterStack called `stack_raw`. The dimensions are `517, 626, 323642, 46  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)` .
I want to add an empty layer to a `n` position.
I´m trying this way, but it sounds a bit stupid:

> ```
> #Creating the empty raster with the same dimensions:
> a<-raster(nrow=517, ncol=626, ext=extent(stack_raw), crs=crs(stack_raw))
> a[]<-1
>
> #Separating the RasterStack in parts, in order to add the layer on that position:
> stack_raw12<-subset(stack_raw, 1:2)
> stack_raw346<-subset(stack_raw, 3:46)
>
> #Adding the layer in the position of the middle:0
> stack_raw12a<-addLayer(stack_raw12, a)
>
> #Joining everybody:
> stack_rawfull<-addLayer(stack_raw12a, stack_raw346)
> ```

Does anyone know a more intelligent way to do that?

Comment: I'd try just subsetting out the ones after stacking all together, i.e. `subset(stack(stack_raw, a), c(1:2, 47, 3:46))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work to `stack` them all together and index that with `subset`:

```
subset(stack(stack_raw, a), 
    c(1:2, 47, 3:46))
```

You could be more nuanced with the index, i.e.

```
nl <- nlayers(stack_raw)
subset(stack(stack_raw, a), 
     c(1:2, nl + 1, 3:nl))
```